# Maven integration test not working with Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, thymeleaf

I am running a database integration test on my current project. I am using maven currently for it. When I run the test some values are not being loaded from my properties files. To load the properties I am using

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties)
```

I am also using thymeleaf to get the values.

```
@Value("${fieldsToSetString}")
private String fieldsToSetString;
```

I believe the issue is that from the tests maven doesn't know that I am using Spring because I am using annotations rather than a traditional web.xml so it does not run my Application.class which specifies that I am using Spring. So maven isn't recognizing the @PropertySource annotation. Anyone know how to solve this issue so that the annotation can be resolved while running the integration test?

Comment: How are you bootstrapping the spring context in your integration test? Are you defining a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your test context?

Comment: I suspect that your "belief" is true as well: Maven doesn't know.....
Annotate your test class with @ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext.xml") 
That should help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean  nomis and adding the annotation you suggest Mubin does not fix the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for @PropertySource to work you need @Configuration as well. This did not solve my problem entirely because the project still would not start when the configuration annotation was put in.